# How can I count the number of detected objects in yolo V3 . I am uisng YOLO v3 with Pytorch

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolo

I am trying to count the detected objects and export them in a .csv format. My object detection is working great but needs some help in terms of counting the number of objects.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Please see guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example while asking a question